# Javascript timer algorithm help, do something once, then clearInterval

Tags: javascript, algorithm, timer, setinterval, reset

On mousemove or scroll I want to reset a timer if it's not running and inside the timer function run a function once. So far I have this...

```
var timerId,
    lastActive = new Date().getTime(),
    token;

var timerFunc = function () {

   var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
   var timeDiff = currentTime - lastActive;
   if (timeDiff > 10000) {
     //clearInterval(timerId);
   }

      //I want to do some logic here
      // but only on the first iteration of the timer
      //how can I do that?

};

$(window).on('mousemove scroll', function (e) {
lastActive = new Date().getTime();

 //only restart the timer if its not currently running. How can I do that??
if(resetTimer)
       timerId = setInterval(timerFunc , 10000);            
 });

 timerId = setInterval(timerFunc , 10000);
```

Can any javascript gurus help me fill in the pieces? I apologize if I'm too brief. I will follow up any questions in the comments. Thank you all for any tips, links, tricks, etc.. Cheers. =)

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what it is you want, could you be more specific about how you want the process to work?

Comment: Well your interval - i.e. the timer - is assigned to `timerId`. So to test if the interval is running, you would use `if (timerID)`, or did I miss something?

Comment: Yes Rey, jQuery is fine. Anthony-- I basically want to do an ajax post. I want the timer function to send one at timer start up and one more if the user hasn't moved the mouse or scrolled in 10 secs for this example. I don't want to send one on every mouse move or scroll, only send if the timer is not currently running.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make use of a boolean variable for first interval(that's easy, just add it after the timer. You've got the right idea in the if(resetTimer) too, to check if it's running just have the timer function set a global variable when it's running and when it stops.

Comment: I'll assume you didn't really mean global variable (evil) and, rather, a variable that is merely accessible by the script (i.e. within the current scope)